# Commit Kafka offsets in Java manually

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a situation (don't ask) where I have offset information (topic, partition, offset) that I need to commit to Kafka from an external service.

Is the only way to do this by creating a KafkaConsumer object and calling commitSync / commitAsync? Or is there a mechanism I've missed where I can make the commit without having to instantiate a KafkaConsumer? Since I won't be doing any consuming from this service, that seems like overkill.

Comment: You will need a consumer to have easy access to the API through which offsets are committed, even if not processing data

Answer (score 1):

With the Java API, I'm not aware of a way to arbitrarily commit offsets without a Consumer.

You can use the `kafka-consumer-groups` tool with the `--reset-offsets` option but under the cover it will create a Consumer.

Several 3rd party clients (such as Sarama or kafka-python) allow sending raw requests. Using such a client (or customizing the Java client) you will be able to send a CommitOffsetRequests directly.

Answer (score 1):

The responsibility of knowing the offset lies within the kafka consumer. This is inherent in the kafka architecture. One of the design decisions that makes kafka so performant is that the responsibility of knowing at which point to consume data is the responsibility of the kafka consumer.